# Match a Deployment ID in Windows Azure

Tags: azure, azure-worker-roles

I have several different services running the same code base as windows azure worker roles.
I'm trying to test and see if the currently executing code is running in a specific instance. If I call to this in the management API:

```
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(
        new Uri("https://management.core.windows.net/" + subscriptionId + "/services/hostedservices/<<servicename>>/deploymentslots/production?embed-detail=true"));
```

I get a response like this:

```
    <Deployment xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/windowsazure" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <Name>c8bd3b12f1bc4e0db9d8c1d59e97e48b</Name>
  <DeploymentSlot>Production</DeploymentSlot>
  <PrivateID>d1ea61e367e84aedb68de97eded3e896</PrivateID>
  <Status>Running</Status>
  <Label>SXRlbVVwZGF0ZXIgLSAzLzEzLzIwMTMgMTA6NDQ6MTUgQU0=</Label>
  <Url>http://itemupdater3.cloudapp.net/</Url>
  <RoleInstanceList>
    <RoleInstance>
      <RoleName>UpdateItems</RoleName>
      <InstanceName>UpdateItems_IN_0</InstanceName>
      <InstanceStatus>Ready</InstanceStatus>
    </RoleInstance>
  </RoleInstanceList>
  <UpgradeDomainCount>1</UpgradeDomainCount>
  <RoleList>
    <Role>
      <RoleName>UpdateItems</RoleName>
      <OsVersion>WA-GUEST-OS-1.22_201302-02</OsVersion>
    </Role>
  </RoleList>
</Deployment>
```

I'm trying to test and see if the currently executing code has the same ID as this response.
If I compare:

```
xml["Deployment"]["Name"].InnerText;
```

To

```
RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Role.Instances[0].Id;
```

It never matches. How do I match something from the C# to the ID returned from the API?
Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're trying to compare the name of the deployment (typically a single guid-like string, unique every time you redeploy) to the name of the instance (follows a pattern of RoleName_IN_xxx).  They will never match.

I'm not 100% sure what you're trying to do, but the call to Service Management API will never give you information on your current instance - because it does not know where you run from; you can even call the API from non-Azure resources.  It will simply give you data about the whole subscription.

RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id will provide you with the ID of the current instance.

Comment: Thanks, Igor. Can I get the ID of the instance also through the service API? Is that "PrivateID" or "Name" or "Label" in the XML Above?

Comment: It is the InstanceName proprety under the RoleInstance element of the RoleInstanceList element

Answer (score 2):

kevin, use the RoleEnvironment.DeploymentId instead of the RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.  This will allow you to compare what is currently running with what you get from the service management API.